# How can I write a custom encoder for the below text in C# .NET

Tags: c#, file, serialization, unicode, encoding

I'm attempting to read a .txt file and place the text into an object. Then later on serialize said object and write to another .txt, all while keeping the exact same characters.

I've tried using 'iso-8859-1' encoding when using `File.ReadAllLines()` but I get following:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0Fxl.png)

I've also tried creating a custom JavascriptEncoder for serialization but that did not work, I'm assuming since the read wasn't even getting the correct characters.

Is there a way I can write a custom encoder for both `File.ReadAllLines()` and `JsonSerializer.Serialize()` so that I can keep the exact same characters throughout. Thanks

Edit : I removed the encoding entirely and it worked for most characters, but still returns 'œ' as 'o'.
Original Text:
sfør
Är du säker på a
un¹æ ko
róciæ kolejnoœæ numeró
e¿y pamiêtaæ, ¿e w
aŸn
nieœ w górê
g³ówna
w³aœc

Comment: But the result you show is in Notepad, not in the debugger from your C# code. If the result of `File.ReadAllLines` is wrong, are you perhaps passing the wrong encoding? What is the encoding used to produce the file you're reading? As far as I'm aware, UTF8 is required by the JSON spec, so why would you want to use a different encoding?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama since json reads/writes *text* (not binary), I would *assume* that it is agnostic on the encoding aspect? I took a look at ecma-404 v2, and the only mention of "utf" is discussing surrogate pairs

Comment: The notepad is the original .txt file I'm reading sorry I didn't specify, the console is what the program is reading. I've managed to get the console to match the notepad without using encoding to begin with. The issue now is when placing that string into an object, and then serializing it, it turns the special characters into \u00F8r for example.

Comment: @Marc Perhaps I'm wrong about it requiring UTF8 specifically, but it does specify that _"JSON syntax describes a sequence of Unicode code points."_, so some form of Unicode is expected at least.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama that just means "the input/output is text"; it says nothing about how that text gets read/written as bytes

Comment: @Marc The older RFC did indicate that a form of unicode should be used for encoding ([source](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159.html#section-8.1)), though it seems like the [newer RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-8.1) makes it clearer that others are acceptable, albeit only as part of a "closed ecosystem". It seems that my memory was still partly wrong though. :)

Comment: "but still returns 'œ' as 'o'." - indeed; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1 *does not have* œ - that's the point of ANSI code-pages: each includes some portion of locale-specific characters, at the cost of excluding others (because there's only 256 characters available); iso-8859-1 drops œ among others, and as such *there is no way of saying that an iso-8859-1 file "contains" œ*, except as a digraph "oe"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, if you're going to read and write text: you need to know what encoding you're meant to be using. You cannot usually guess. There's not really any such thing as a "text file"; there's just a binary file that your code is going to translate to text via an encoding; either the system can guess, or you can tell it. These days, UTF8 is a pragmatic default, and ANSI encodings such as iso-8859-1 should *usually* be considered legacy and reserved for handling data that is limited to that specific codepage for historic reasons

So, either:

1. determine what encoding you're meant to be using and use that for both read and write, or
2. treat the data as raw bytes, without attempting to parse it into string (etc) data

Comment: I was told to use 'iso-8859-1' yet that doesn't seem to work. Like the edit says I tried without using encoding and it works for the most part. The issue now is serializing the string into a json and writing that to the file. The resulting txt file has the special characters replaced with '\u00F8r' and others. I tried a custom JsonSerializerOption but that doesn't help:
```JsonSerializerOptions serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions();
                serializerOptions.Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.Create(UnicodeRanges.All);```

Comment: @MiguelAzzopardi "I was told to use 'iso-8859-1' yet that doesn't seem to work" - then (one of) a: you were told wrong, b: you were told right, but some file was written incorrectly, c: you were told right and the file was written right, but your expectations about what the file contains were wrong, or d: the data is indeed meant to be iso-8859-1, but someone tried to store a character that *does not exist in that code-page* (each ANSI code-page only allows 256 characters, most of which are shared; the fraction of unicode that works in any given ANSI code-page is 0.39%)

Comment: @MiguelAzzopardi with the edit, it looks like "d" is our winner; iso-8859-1 literally does not have œ

Comment: I see, so I've managed to get it reading and writing to the file in the exact way it was read, including the 'œ' character. Did this using ```Encoding.Default``` for reading and writing. The only issue that remains is serializing the string using this ```Encoding.Default``` as the encoding for ```JsonSerializerOptions```.